# Creating new polygons from a detailed shapefile

Tags: r, dictionary, plot, subset, shapefile

Is there any fast way to construct a new shapefile using a more detailed one? The example below will present the problem.

Using data available in this [link](ftp://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/malhas_digitais/municipio_2010/sp.zip) it is possible to obtain São Paulo municipalities.

```
if(require(rgdal) == F){install.packages('rgdal'); require(rgdal)}
if(require(ggplot2) == F){install.packages('ggplot2'); require(ggplot2)}
setwd("..data directory..")
sp4.rg <- readOGR(".", "35MUE250GC_SIR")
plot(sp4.rg, axes=TRUE, border="gray")
```

[image: sao paulo municipalities]

In this plot there are 645 municipalities. I want to do the same plot, but now I want to agregate some of this municipalities in a new region (polygon). For example: Let's call this new region as "SPABCD". This region is composed with the following municipalities: "SÃO PAULO", "SÃO BERNARDO DO CAMPO",  "SANTO ANDRÉ", "SÃO CAETANO" and "DIADEMA".

```
sp <- fortify(sp4.rg, region = "NM_MUNICIP")
spabcd <- c("SÃO PAULO", "SÃO BERNARDO DO CAMPO",  "SANTO ANDRÉ", "SÃO CAETANO DO SUL", "DIADEMA")
sp$region <- ifelse(sp$id %in% spabcd, "SPABCD", sp$id)
```

My question is: there is a fast way (an already created function) to select the latitudes and longitudes that surround this new region in a way that it will be possible to plot it?

Comment: This [maptools vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maptools/vignettes/combine_maptools.pdf) might help get you started.

Comment: Thank you @hrbrmstr! I will see it!

Comment: +1 to @hrbrmstr's indirect suggestion to use `maptools::unionSpatialPolygons()`. Also, as a general rule, you'll want to do all of your manipulations of `Spatial*` objects *before* `fortify()`'ing them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One *quick*/toy example with your data (since it's going to take more work on your part to do this, I believe):

```
library(maptools)

regs <- c("S\xc3O PAULO", "S\xc3O BERNARDO DO CAMPO", 
          "SANTO ANDR\xc9", "S\xc3O CAETANO DO SUL", "DIADEMA")

# make a copy of all the IDs
sp2 <- sp$ID

# filter out only the ones we want dissolved:
sp2[which(!sp$NM_MUNICIP %in% regs)] <- NA
sp.u <- unionSpatialPolygons(sp, sp2)

# sample new plot
plot(sp.u)
```

[image]

```
# showing this region on the whole map

plot(sp, axes=TRUE, border="gray")
plot(sp.u, col="red", add=TRUE)
```

[image]

And, now, with just the border:

```
# make one "bin"
sp.u.s <- getSpPPolygonsLabptSlots(sp.u)

outline <- cut(sp.u.s[,1], range(sp.u.s[,1]), include.lowest=TRUE)

# one more dissolve
dissolved <- unionSpatialPolygons(sp.u ,outline)

plot(sp, axes=TRUE, border="gray")
plot(dissolved, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @hrbrmstr. Is it possible to plot just the border? Actually, I do not want to plot just this subset, I want the whole map with this region.

Comment: Thank you again @hrbrmstr. Is it possible to plot just the border of the region?

Comment: One last mod updated :-) You can add `col="white"` to have it appear to be one contiguous region on the map. But, you can do tons more if you read that PDF in the original comment :-)

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maptools/vignettes/combine_maptools.pdf  + https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/scicomp/usecases/PolygonDissolveOperationsR (forgot that link earlier)